# Object remapping problem - property undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Alright, I am probably overlooking something extremely obvious, but I cannot figure out why this is happening (both in Firefox and Chrome). Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <style type="text/css">
  body, html { background-color: #ffffff; }
  div { text-align: center; color: #000000; }
  table, th, td { border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse; }
  table { table-layout: fixed; }
  th,td { padding: 5px; }
  #err { background-color: #ff0000; }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function main() {
   if(document.readyState == 'complete') {
    var Arr = [
     {a: 'a0', b: 'b0', c: 'c0'},
     {a: 'a1', b: 'b1', c: 'c1'},
     {a: 'a2', b: 'b2', c: 'c2'},
     {a: 'a3', b: 'b3', c: 'c3'},
     {a: 'a4', b: 'b4', c: 'c4'}
    ];
    var strErr;
    var strMsg;
    var strRsl = document.querySelector('#rsl').innerHTML;
    document.querySelector('#prc').addEventListener('click', getResults, false);

    function getResults() {
     strErr = '';
     strMsg = strRsl;
     document.querySelector('#err').innerHTML = strErr;
     document.querySelector('#rsl').innerHTML = strMsg;
     Arr = Arr.map(remap);
    }
    function remap(value, index, array) {
     return {
      d: value.a,
      e: value.a.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_'),
      f: value.c.toLowerCase(),
      g: value.b,
      h: '',
      k: -1
     };
    }
   } else {
    setTimeout(function() { main(); }, 1000);
   }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript: main();">
 <div>
  <input type="button" id="prc" value="Do Stuff" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <p id="err"></p>
  <table id="msg" align="center">
   <tr><th>d</th><th>e</th><th>f</th><th>g</th><th>h</th><th>k</th></tr>
   <tfoot id="rsl" align="center"></tfoot>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox console returns (line 39):

> TypeError: value.a is undefined

Chrome console returns (line 39):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Under certain circumstances, when the same error occurs, the object can still get remapped successfully, for some magical reason. Also, the object only seems to get created after the "Do Stuff" button is clicked twice.

Does it have something to do with the fact that it's instantiated within a function that only gets called upon page load?

Comment: After the first `remap` call. `Arr` becomes an array of objects which have no `a` properties, thus `e: value.a.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_'),` throws because there is no `value.a`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, you are right. Now that was silly. Could you please add it as an answer, so that the question can get resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first `remap` call. `Arr` becomes an array of objects which have no `a` properties, thus `e: value.a.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_'),` throws because there is no `value.a`.

If you want the mapping to always succeed, either always assign a string to an `a` (and `c`) property of the returned object, or omit the `e` and `f` properties if, on the input object, `a` or `c` don't exist.

Comment: Thank you once more for being kind enough to point it out to me. I will accept your answer once I am allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it have something to do with the fact that it's instantiated within a function that only gets called upon page load?

No. You can move the script tag to the lower body tag for taking off the if-load and timeout.
[Or add "defer" attribute](https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/) and put into an external file with src="external/path/script.js"

to exemplify @CertainPerformance comment:

```
var remap = v => ({
    d: v.a,
    e: v.a.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_'),
    f: v.c.toLowerCase(),
    g: v.b,
    h: '',
    k: -1
})
var Arr = [
    {a: 'a0', b: 'b0', c: 'c0'},
    {a: 'a1', b: 'b1', c: 'c1'},
    {a: 'a2', b: 'b2', c: 'c2'},
    {a: 'a3', b: 'b3', c: 'c3'},
    {a: 'a4', b: 'b4', c: 'c4'}
]
var ArrMappedOnce = Arr.map(remap)
var ArrMappedTwice = ArrMappedOnce.map(remap) //it bugs
```

Maybe you will like [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var remap2 = v => Object.assign(v, {
    d: v.a,
    e: v.a.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_'),
    f: v.c.toLowerCase(),
    g: v.b,
    h: '',
    k: -1
})
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the examples and other ways of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 0):

no more `a` fileld:

you need change keys on which exist:
[image]